# How would I make a playlist editor for mp3 flash object?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an mp3 player embedded into my site and would like to have a box on my site where they can edit playlist. I need to know, How would I begin to make a playlist editor in php for an mp3 flash object? 
     ..So they may add songs/edit songs/delete song if posted , etc

```
    <object style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:400px;z-index:12;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3.swf" width="200" height="20">
            <param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3.swf" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#94C0DF" />
            <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=http%3A//flash-mp3-player.net/medias/another_world.mp3&amp;volume=50&amp;showinfo=1&amp;bgcolor=94C0DF&amp;bgcolor1=B4E8FB&amp;bgcolor2=B4E8FB&amp;buttoncolor=330026&amp;slidercolor1=888888&amp;sliderovercolor=00d600" />
    </object>
```

Comment: for start you need to make shure you're swf player accepts playlists , from the above code it seams it accepts a single mp3 file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [user forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/flashmp3player/_Ka4agGX5-0/discussion) of "flash-mp3-player.net", you just serve up the playlist in a particular text format. So you'll want to use some kind of database to associate "playlists" with the "tracks" there, and when someone requests a given "playlist", you query that database and generate output of the correct format (as specified in the above URL) as the response.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did look at the site but didn't find anything on it +1